# How to have particles pursue a target around obstacles

Tags: game-engine, particles

In Blender Game Engine, it is possible to have an object purse a goal around an obstacle using a 'steering' actuator and 'path following' behavior.

[image: bge path following]

[image: path following setup]

Is it possible to do the same thing using particles. I'd like to have a particle system find a path around an obstacle to get to a goal.

[image: particle system]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to give each particle a steering actuator too.

Ensure that these particle objects are recognized as obstacles.